# Loading style sheet(xhtml file), dynamically

Tags: java, spring, jsf, xhtml, richfaces

I am trying to reload a style sheet (written in xhtml), dynamically.

To describe the scenario:

The application can be accessed by the user in multiple languages; First time when the application loads, a default file master-styles.xhtml is loaded, and now the user from some control screen can modify the language in which user wants to view the screen. Now at this point I want to load a different stylesheet for that specific language, scrapping the currently used stylesheet (master-styles.xhtml);

I am using JSF, richfaces for the UI components:

```
<html>
     <head>

<sf:includeStyles />
  <ui:insert name="globalStyles">
      <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/ui/core/resources/styles/master-styles.xhtml"/>
  </ui:insert>
</head>
```

Is there a way to discard this file and load another file as part of my CSS; or is there an alternate way by which i can counter this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to dynamically load the page which is right now `/master-styles.xhtml` ,

You can set the page name in bean and then using this code you can dynamically load the style page needed

```
<ui:insert name="globalStyles">
      <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/ui/core/resources/styles/#{ThemeBean.stylePage}.xhtml"/>
  </ui:insert>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried accessing it via the resource bundle, but the ui:include tag doesn't seem to evaluate the value of the resource bundle, and causing a 404 page not found exception

Comment: @Abdul no not resource bundle ThemeBean is a simple session scoped bean holding the theme style user has selected

Comment: I am working on a Spring based framework, can i still be able to use it?

Comment: @Abdul The bean I indicated will be your jsf session scoped bean

Comment: I doubt that its substituting the value on runtime in the iclude tag; I used   <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/ui/core/resources/styles/#{conversationScope.stylePage}.xhtml"/> ; but with no success, it again throws a page not found exception

Comment: 1.conversationScope is session scoped bean 2. it has a Sting field `stylePage` with proper setters getter. and 3. I hope there is a page with the generated sting ,

Comment: The application I am working on is designed in Spring, and the conversationScope in Spring is similar to a Session scope, it still shows me a runtime 404 exception. Before the page is fetched my Model objects are called successfully and the data for that is printed in the logs, but when the flow reaches the view page, it crashes, it doesn't identify the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed an alternate way to tackle this type of problem. Richfaces features *skins*, which allow you to change the appearance of all components at once. It also supports switching skins at runtime (e.g. so that a user can choose his/her own theme). More info on this feature is available on the [Richfaces wiki](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#Skinnability), and the switching is covered in section *5.11.7, Changing skin in runtime*